# Java, Runtime errors

Tags: java, runtime-error

What happens when you see these runtime errors while you are executing your program.

1. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at WhatHappens.main(WhatHappens.java:7)`
2. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WhatHappen`
3. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at WhatHappens.main(WhatHappens.java:6)`

Comment: what's the question?? post some code, or I think this post will be closed and removed

Comment: You have to end up fixing them. :)

Comment: Well, most of the time we try to remove them. I think I answered your question.

Comment: You curse under your breath, "Blast! Another bug!" and then set about spending another few hours fixing it.

Comment: The long story is beyond the scope of this comment. The true story is we identify where the problem occur and fix the problem.

Comment: What *has* happened is that you had a bug in your application and this triggered an error which was logged.  What this means for you application depends on what it is doing. What it means for you is you have a bug to fix.

Comment: What I'm actually looking for is e.g. runtime error NullPointerException, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the Question is really meant to be what HAS HAPPENED:

1. You have attempted to dereference a `null`; e.g. invoke a method using it, access a field using it and so on.  This is often caused by some code neglecting to initialize a class or instance variable, or array element.
2. Class loading or class initialization has failed.  There are a variety of things that can cause this.
3. You have tried to index an array using an index value that is beyond the range allowed; i.e. the index value is less than zero, or greater than `array.length - 1`.

---

If you really want to know what happens after the exception is thrown, the answer is that unless some code catches the exception, the current thread or the entire application dies.

What you should do next is to find the cause of the problem and fix it.  And the key to that is to understand what caused the exception to be thrown in the first place; see above.  Examine the stacktrace, read the error message, read the classname/line number from the stacktrace to work out where the code was ... and use your analytical ability to figure out what specifically caused the problem.

Answer (score -1):

java run time error mostly occurs due to improper setting of environment variable.this can be done by right click on my computer there is a option called environment variable and add your java jdk bin path to it.
eg.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin

[jre error solved](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wekrWcJTGdo)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for trying to answer this old question however I do not think it truly answers it as you are detailing a general problem with how Java is often set-up by end-users - where as the question shows several specific errors which they are asking about.